# Чем канонические геттеры и сеттеры лучше открытого поля?

Tags: java, ооп

Не понимаю, в чем плюс использования канонических (только возвращающих и устанавливающих занчение) геттеров и сеттеров перед открытым полем? Чем вот такой код:

```
private MyJDesktopPane desktop;

public MyJDesktopPane getDesktop() {
    return desktop;
}

public void setDesktop(MyJDesktopPane desktop) {
    this.desktop = desktop;
}
```

Лучше такого:

```
public MyJDesktopPane desktop;
```

Понимаю, если в сеттере например используются какие-либо проверки на корректность введенного значения или идет согласование введенного значения с другими полями класса.

Скажу честно, до проблемы додумался не сам, прочитал о ней в статье ["10 приемов, разрушающих хрупкую красоту кода"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/59570/) на Хабре.

Comment: Тем что можно синхронно с установкой значения поля или извлечения его значения выполнить какой-то сопутствующий код для автоматического получения необходимых  побочных эффектов. В сеттере можно выполнить проверку, что значение, которое кто-то пытается пропихнуть в поле, соответствует каким-то правилам. Если ничего этого не надо, если нужна только ячейка для хранения чего-либо, то конечно и геттеры/сеттеры не нужны

Comment: Если ты потом надумаешь всё таки добавить проверки на корректность или еще что, не нужно будет переделывать. И да, хабр не обязательно истина.

Comment: Ничем не лучше. Когда захочешь получить доступ к какому-нибудь низкоуровневому проприетарному интерфейсу, будешь долго материть разработчиков, которые слишком сильно любили инкапсуляцию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это "запас на будущее".

Сейчас вам достаточно поля, так как у вас публичны и чтение, и запись, а никакой дополнительной логики нет. Теперь допустим, что вам понадобилась эта логика. Что вы будете делать? Вы скроете поле, напишете геттеры и сеттеры. И тут возникает проблема: надо переписать все доступы к полю во всех классах, работающих с вашим кодом; надо перекомпилировать весь код, который обращается к полю. Часто это может быть большой объём работы, и он может повлечь за собой тьму тьмущую неприятностей, особенно если одновременно поддерживается несколько версий приложения: привет конфликтам мержа кода и прочим радостям.

Всё потому, что изменение поля на геттеры и сеттеры — это **изменение, ломающее обратную совместимость**, а добавление логики в геттер или сеттер — совершенно безболезненное **изменение реализации**. При хорошей архитектуре изменение реализации не должно влиять на внешний интерфейс и не должно ломать обратную совместимость. Поэтому предпочтение отдаётся геттерам и сеттерам даже тогда, когда реальной нужды в них нет.

Лирическое отступление: в C# синтаксис доступа к публичным полям и к публичным свойствам (парам геттер+сеттер) идентичен. Однако даже в C# считается дурным тоном использование публичных полей. Во-первых, потому что ломается бинарная совместимость, несмотря на сохранение совместимости на уровне сорцов; во-вторых, потому что публичные поля могут быть переданы по ссылке (`ref`, `out`), что невозможно для свойств.

---

Прочитал статью. Надо заметить, что рекомендация воздерживаться от геттеров и сеттеров в статье универсальна и оторвана от конкретных языков. Нельзя реализовать все рекомендации из статьи, если оставаться в рамках синтаксически аскетичного языка. Вы не можете воспользоваться синтаксическии сахаром в виде свойств, которые выразительнее, чем геттеры и сеттеры, если язык эти свойства не поддерживает. В этом случае придётся использовать геттеры и сеттеры, а не публичные поля, впрочем. Ну или переходите на C#. :)

Comment: спасибо огромное! Очень понятно все разъяснили.

Answer (score 3):

В вызваном из контекста примере ничем. Например разницы между

```
class A {
    public int a;
}
```

и

```
class A {
    private int a;

    public int getA() { return a; }
    public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

нет.

Однако, в любой более менее адекватной ситуации лучше использовать getter'ы и setter'ы, причины могут быть следующие

1. Поле нельзя вынести в интерфейс. Даже если сейчас у класса нет интерфейса, но его захочется добавить позже, гораздо проще будет переделать методы, чем жёсткую привязку к полю.
2. Если будет требоваться добавить дополнительную логику при установке поля, то так же изменений будет требоваться минимум.
3. Метод можно пометить как synchronized.

Таким образом можно сделать вывод, что по большей части мы обеспечиваем расширяемость.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что один из принципов ООП это как раз инкапсуляция - скрытие внутренней логики класса. Если другие классы будут иметь прямой доступ к публичной переменной класса - тогда вообще возникает вопрос, почему этот класс ей "обладает", если реально - не обладает :) 
В общем логика программы будет страдать, опасность путаницы и одновременного доступа из разных методов и т.д.. Хочется публичных переменных, и методы только заполняющие поля - заводи структуру.

Comment: Почему тогда разрешено делать public поля. Ввели бы на них ограничение private и protected и no modifier только.

Comment: В настоящем ООП нет никаких структур. Всё есть классы!

Comment: А почему указатель может быть неопределенным, если обращение к нему обязательно приведет к краху программы? Если что то можно делать, не значит, что это логически правильно. А по поводу "чем отличается класс от структуры" - это воообще вопрос, "вызывающий бесконечные прения".

Comment: А в жаве, о которой речь, нет структур. И соответственно бесконечных прений нет. :P

Comment: @Mira, в Java нет структур. И наверное они не являются решением проблемы. Например, у меня в классе есть и другие поля, у которых сеттеры вполне осмысленные, выполняющие определенную логику. И только одно поле с каноническими геттерами и сеттерами. Мне что для него одного структуру заводить? А про инкапсуляцию.. понятно что внутреннюю логику надо скрывать, я и не спрашивал про те сеттеры, которые что то делают. А только про те, которые просто устанавливают значение поля.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, что публичные поля имеют право на существование в некоторых случаях:

1. Поля объявлены в непубличном классе. Тогда весь класс — это деталь реализации и с полями может быть проще и быстрее, чем с сеттерами.
2. Поля объявлены `final` и содержат примитивное значение, либо ссылку на неизменяемый объект (например, `String`). Сеттера тогда, понятно, не будет, а геттером можно в принципе пожертвовать. Но в этом случае учтите, что финальность поля — часть контракта и вы не можете в будущем взять и убрать слово `final`: пользователи могут заложиться на то, что ваше поле нельзя неконтролируемо изменить.